# Viewing Web OS Logs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana, webos

Previously Eclipse (with the Aptana plugin) was showing debug logs whenever I ran an application on Web OS. However, I'm not seeing them anymore. How can I bring them back?

Comment: Check that the log level is set correctly.  Not sure if there's something fancy you can do in Eclipse, but if you do a `palm-log --system-log-level=info` you'll be sure to capture all log messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that the console window is showing. Then, Eclipse has an option "Display Selected Console" in the toolbar above the console window. An option with the id of your application should appear here - if it doesn't and the application is running, try restarting.